# Couldn't connect to a firebird database from javaFX application in Raspberry Pi

Tags: java, linux

hi i'm new to Raspberry Pi .

I have created a javafx application using netbeans in windows.my application uses firebird for DB purposes and uses jaybird jarapplication works fine with windows,centos ,but my application could not connect to the database from Raspberry Pi.
database is located on a windows machine.

Do I need to install anything for firebird access in Raspberry Pi ?

here is my code

```
String db_ip = "192.168.1.14",db_path ="D:\\QUEUE_NEW.GDB";
Class.forName("org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver");
try {
    con = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:firebirdsql://" + db_ip + ":3050/" +
                                       db_path + "", "SYSDBA", "masterkey");
    st = con.createStatement();
} 
catch (SQLException ex) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "firebird sql.");
}
```

please help me out to resolve this issue

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the `db_path` is where the problem is. `D:\...` won't be available as a path from the Pi, so either you'll need a DB alias here or mount the windows box share from the Pi and have the `db_path` be something like `/mnt/windowsbox/QUEUE_NEW.GD`.

Cheers,

Comment: how to mount windows box share from the pi

Comment: 1) create share on windows machine 2) `mount -t cifs //windowsmachine/sharename /mnt/windowsbox -o username=uid,password=pw`

Comment: No, provided that the Firebird client jar is packaged with your FX application.